# Position of 'both' or 'equally' in regard to prepositions (to both reassure OR both to reassure)

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

> 1) This helps both to reassure existing users and (to) attract new users.
>
> 2) This helps to both reassure existing users and (to) attract new users.

I'm pretty sure the second one is a correct phrase. However, I tend to instinctively use the first one and I'm not 100% sure whether that is also correct usage. A variant of this question would replace 'both' with 'equally'.

EDIT: Third variant:

> 3) This both helps to reassure existing users and (to) attract new users.

Comment: I do believe both are correct

Comment: In 2) you've split the infinitive, in 1) you've left it intact by placing "both" before "to reassure". The difference is the same as Star Trek's line "To boldly go..." or "To go boldly..."  You've just placed both in a different position and doesn't change its meaning as far as I know. Split infinitives is one of those rules that used to be controversial a long time ago before most people realised that English isn't Latin. I hope the opposition to it has completely died out. I mean the belief, not the people.

Comment: Thanks, I have gotten completely hung up on the word 'both' (that I tend to use a lot) to not see the split infinitive aspect. The position of the word 'both' has been a longstanding dispute between a German and an Italian, neither of us being confident enough to cast a definitive ruling on it.